# DOMPurify Keep text between tags || Remove only Tags

Tags: javascript, xss, html-injections, dompurify

I have an Test string.

```
const html = '{%remove%} useful {{remove}} <svg></p><style><a id="</style><img src=1 onerror=alert(1)>"> keep';
```

And I'm trying to remove all the html content and the *{{*, *}}*, *{%*, *%}*. But I'd like to keep the **useful** and **keep** words on string.

```
const purifyConfig = {
    FORBID_TAGS: ['{{', '{%',],
    SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES: true,
    RETURN_TRUSTED_TYPE: true,
    ALLOW_DATA_ATTR: false,
    KEEP_CONTENT: true,
};
const clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(html, purifyConfig);
```

The clean Result in a Empty string.
What configuration should I use to do this?

Comment: I think you just need `DOMPurify.sanitize(html, {SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES: true, ADD_TAGS: ['{%']})`. the SAFE_FOR_TEMPLATES option is for `{{`-`}}` and `<%`-`%>`

Comment: This options still remove all string. And ADD_TAGS doesn't recognize the {%%} pattern